# How do I map a texture correctly onto a convex polygon in SFML or OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, polygon, sfml, texture-mapping

I want to represent my Objects as textured convex Polygons. For the most part those will just be rotated rectangles but i want to support convex shapes too and thats where the problems arise.

I worked with Blender a while ago and there you could unwrap the 3D-Objects and explicetely tell Blender which vertex of the Shape has which Position on the Texture.

Would it maybe be better to just request the Texture to have the size of the bounding Rectangle of the Shape so I can just apply the texture with SFML?

PS: Im sorry i cant post pictures to clarify my question.

Comment: Why don't just use `sf::ConvexShape` and `setTexture` for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or OpenGL

In OpenGL, typically you'll have two (or more!) vertex attributes: position and texture coordinate. That's basically saying *which vertex of the Shape has which Position on the Texture*.

That's what SFML *has* to be doing internally, and since its Open-Source, you might just peek inside and see if your "bounding rectangle" idea has a chance of working (my guess is that it indeed does).

Comment: Yes I tested an it worked but I think it would be more comfortable to create a texture and then decide how it is mapped onto the shape than having to decide first how it is mappes and then having to create the texture after it.
The way I see it it would reduce the reusability of my textures as theyre object specific

As you say it works with texture coordinates in OpenGL, I researched it before asking and never found someone explaining them as being "The position of the Vertex on the Texture" Have you maybe got some links with good material to read abou it :)?

Comment: *never found someone explaining them as being "The position of the Vertex on the Texture"* - maybe you just didn't understand it that way. The fact is that a particular texture and a particular set of coords have to match anyway, and when changing a texture, you might be changing some image data, but the mapping hardly changes at all, at least in all practical scenarios I know of.

Comment: I think you understood me wrong.
Supposing I would do it with the "bounding rectangle" approach every texture would be specific to one Shape and would be hard to be reused. For example on a different Object with same shape but differant rotation(thus resulting in the texture having a wrong rotation too)

Comment: No, because the transformation applied to the vertices to rasterize them wouldn't apply to texture coordinates. At least shouldn't, I stopped using SFML precisely because it tried to be "too smart" at times. Nothing stops you from trying, though.

Comment: @Paul anyway, [take a look at this](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Shape.cpp#L239-L248).

Comment: Its very hard to describe this without an imgae but ill try.

I got a world and in this world i want the user to create polygons by setting its verticies at any position in the world. then the User should be able to choose a texture and specify which vertex is where on that texture. As far As i now that isnt possible in default SFML. All the workarounds I can think of bring further problems into play and seem messy to me. -> So i gues the best thing todo is to create a Polygon class on my own with OpenGL and make it do what i want to(You say it is possible to achieve what i want to in OpenGL)?

Comment: @Paul why don't you inherit from `SFML::Shape` and replace `updateTexCoords` function? That seems like a simpler approach.

Comment: Because Im not that much into SFML internals and it also provides support for OpenGL drawing. But the biggest reason is because I dont know how. Btw I just read you shouldnt chat in the comments maybe we should move somewhere else? and i think your talking about SFML 1.6, i think you mean sf::convexshape

Comment: @Paul you'd need 20 reputation to join chat, but once you do, feel free [to ping me here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89710/chat-for-q-32584681).

Comment: Logging in/out doesnt help